# Existence of a function with certain integral properties

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Does there exist a non-negative Borel-measurable function $g:\mathbb [1,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty}g(y)^2\,\mathrm dy<&\,\infty,\\
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{y}}\,\mathrm dy=&\,\infty?
\end{align*}
$g(y)=1/\sqrt{y}$ “almost” works, but yet it doesn't. In fact, no function of the form $g(y)=1/y^{m}$ with $m>0$ works, because the first condition would imply that $2m>1$ and the second would require that $m+1/2\leq1$, and these two inequalities are incompatible.

Intuitively, $g$ must decline “much faster” than $1/\sqrt{y}$ so as to make the integral of $g(y)^2$ convergent, yet not so fast as to make the integral of $g(y)/\sqrt{y}$ convergent.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. $$g(y)=\frac{\chi_{[2,\infty)}(y)}{\sqrt{y}\log y}.$$

Comment: $\chi_{[2,\infty)}$ is a step function?

Comment: $$\chi_{[2,\infty)}(y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $y\geq 2$,}\\0&\text{if $y\in[1,2)$.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: That's a step function, yes. But do you really need it? It's there to keep the log from blowing up, but $\log(y+1)$ would avoid that...

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, a step function; in fact, it is a very simple one: an indicator function. (Step functions are more general.)

Comment: Eh, I come from a physics background: to us step functions are always Heaviside.

Comment: I see. I love math but I'm as dumb at physics as it gets. :-)